# add close button to appear in div elements without modifying mark-up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if it's possible to add, and then of course style, my `close` button that would simply close the current element *(or hide current div)* on click. I want to do this without manually going into the mark-up and writing the html for a close div. I'm wondering if a purely jQuery or JavaScript solution is possible.

Comment: sure it's possible, common and not difficult...won't get much help without sample html though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".Content-Div").append("<button class='close-btn'>Close Me</div>");
$(".close-btn").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(800);
})
```

```css
.Content-Div {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 20px 4%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.close-btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: #FFF;
  font: 20px Arial;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Content-Div">
  Content
</div>

<div class="Content-Div">
  Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'X';
button.onclick = function() {
  this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
};
document.getElementById('close-me').appendChild(button);
```

```html
<div id="close-me">
  Close me please!
</div>
```